# Positioning elements in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack

The user has the option of entering his own data in Firestore. After that, the data is retrieved from the database in ImageCard. Each time the user adds new data, a new ImageCard is added. I would like the data to be added as in the picture. If only one element is added, let it occupy only 50% of the screen as the third element in the image. If another one is added, I want it to be next to the first element. If a third is added, let it appear below the first and so on. Here is the image:
[https://ibb.co/jZJzhnQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pNL3.png)

Is the above even possible to achieve in Jetpack Compose? This is part of my current code. Currently, the elements are one below the other.

```
accountViewModel.retriveDataFromFirestore(db, userUid.toString()) { projects ->
                    projectsListState.value = projects
                }

                for (project in projectsListState.value) {
                    val imagePainter = rememberImagePainter(data = project.image)
                    val title = "${project.title ?: ""}"
                    Box (modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.5f).padding(16.dp)) {
                        accountViewModel.ImageCard(painter = imagePainter, contentDescription = null, title = title)
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will produce something similar to what you are looking for with a grid of 4:

```
    Column() {
        val imageSizeModifier = Modifier
            .height(175.dp)
            .width(150.dp)

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = imageSizeModifier,
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.mouse),
                contentDescription = "stringResource(id = R.string.content_description)"
            )
            Spacer(
                Modifier
                    .height(10.dp)
                    .width(25.dp)
            )
            Image(
                modifier = imageSizeModifier,
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.otter),
                contentDescription = "stringResource(id = R.string.content_description)"
            )
        }
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = imageSizeModifier,
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.lynx),
                contentDescription = "stringResource(id = R.string.content_description)"
            )
            Spacer(
                Modifier
                    .height(10.dp)
                    .width(25.dp)
            )
            Image(
                modifier = imageSizeModifier,
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.lion),
                contentDescription = "stringResource(id = R.string.content_description)"
            )
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

In your for loop you can save the painter for each to a variable or an array and then use them afterwards outside of the loop.